# Picking triangles in OpenGL core profile when using glDrawElements

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I am drawing a mesh of triangles using glDrawElements and would like to be able to pick/select a triangle using the mouse click. The mesh of triangles can be very big.

In fixed-function OpenGL there is the possibility of using GL_SELECT:
http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Picking
.. However I am only interested in using OpenGL core profile.

Another possibility would be to use 'color coding':

http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/index.php?color1

http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm

.. but as far as I know its not possible to indicate per triangle information yet when using glDrawElements?

Finally I could do CPU based picking by shooting a pick ray through the mouse location, but this would be quite slow since I guess I would have to transform the triangles on the CPU, so I would prefer a GPU based solution.

Does anyone have a suggestion on what is the best way do picking when using glDrawElements in OpenGL core profile?

Comment: Are your vertices used several time for different triangles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About the 'color coding' approach, you could use [gl_PrimitiveID](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_PrimitiveID.xml) to fill the color coded buffer(s) using a proper fragment shader, this would basically give you the index of the drawn triangle.

About the CPU based picking, you could use an existing library that handles the acceleration structures, and ray-mesh intersection, such as [Bullet](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/) or [Opcode](http://www.codercorner.com/Opcode.htm).

The 'best' option for you depends of your use case, hard to tell.

Comment: `gl_PrimitiveID` only works within a single draw call. Among many draw calls, the `gl_PrimitiveID` changes.

Comment: @NicolBolas Of course, to handle multiple objects/draw calls, one should add another parameter to be able to distinguish triangle 0 from two different objects. A per-object uniform combined with `gl_PrimitiveID` should do the trick. Am I missing something?

Comment: rotoglup: Thanks a lot, I did not know about gl_PrimitiveID. I will try it out and let you know how it works. For now I only have one object with many triangles, which is a simpler case.

Comment: @rotoglup: Just one last question. How do i code the color in a floating point number on the GPU and then translate it back again to a triangle id on the cpu? I thought that i could do it using bit operations on floats but its more difficult than i thought.

Comment: @WesDec This could be the topic of another question, but roughly, if your target platform allows it you could simply output the integer value in an [integer texture](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GL_EXT_texture_integer), or find the appropriate formula to encode your int in RGBA8, something along the lines of http://www.ozone3d.net/blogs/lab/20080604/glsl-float-to-rgba8-encoder/ - sorry I don't have the exact answer ready at hand.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing it this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264346/problems-outputting-gl-primitiveid-to-custom-frame-buffer-object-fbo

Answer (score 3):

Try seeing it from this perspective: OpenGL is only meant for drawing things. Picking should be done in another way. If you insist on using OpenGL for it (not unreasonable), use a FBO with a integer 16 bit single channel color buffer attachment, into which you render the object ID. Picking reduces to read the one pixel for the ID.

> Finally I could do CPU based picking by shooting a pick ray through the mouse location, but this would be quite slow since I guess I would have to transform the triangles on the CPU, so I would prefer a GPU based solution.

I recommend this. However instead of transforming all the triangles, just inversely transform your one picking ray. You should manage you scene in some spatial subdivision structure anyway, so testing against that should be trivial.

Comment: Thanks! I dont have a spatial structure (I dont need it for now), but I will try the inverse transform method you suggest the brute-force way. Dont know why I didn't think about that :)

Answer (score 2):

Well you can indeed provide per triangle information on a DrawElements call. You then will have to provide the corresponding arrays (the former COLOR_ARRAY, TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, etc., now commonly called VertexAttribArrays).
This would be probably the easiest solution if you insist on the GPU.

However, usually the way to go would be to fire a ray from the click point into your scene. Consequently, what you will have to do is not to transform each triangle, but to calculate
an intersection test between your ray and your triangles. If the ray intersects, you hit it, 
if not you didn't. This indeed could come at quite some cost if you do it brute force.

However, usually you will have your triangles contained within some spatial data structure (i.e. your scene graph will/can/should have a few representations) like a octree (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) for example. This will allow for a collision response
in quite a few tests. Additionally you can take into account the the final size a triangle will occupy on the screen (so it would be quite meaningless to select subpixel triangles in
most cases).

And if you really want to get fancy, you can put the whole process to the GPU, too (one example that sounds interesting is e.g. http://blog.xeolabs.com/ray-picking-in-scenejs, but there will be more coming up when you use google).

I personally thing the easiest to implement is solution b) Software Ray Picking, then a) and finally GPU picking. Start of with the easiest, improve if you figure it is not fast enough. Don't be caught by too much premature optimization (e.g. ray-cast picking works perfectly well on my iPhone ;). Have fun and good luck with your picking algo.

Comment: `COLOR_ARRAY`, `TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY`, etc are all fixed-function arrays. They're not available in the core profile.

Comment: Yeah same sh**, different name ;) Added VertexAttribArray's for clarity.

Comment: cli_hit: those are vertex attributes (or 'per vertex information'). What I meant was that there is no corresponding triangle attributes (or 'per triangle information'). E.g. it is not possible to indicate a color or normal per triangle; you can only do that per vertex.

Comment: Well, when you use plain triangles, its quite clear - vertex attribute == triangle attribute. If you use strips, you ought to be careful which one you specify, but you can establish a correspondence here also. Should be no problem.

Comment: cli_hit: You are right but its not exactly the same thing. Vertex attributes are typically shared among several triangles and are therefore not "per triangle". For example, if I were to give you a unique color for each triangle in a mesh then how would you color the mesh using a single call to glDrawElements? If there was something like a "TriangleAttribArray" it would be quite easy.

Comment: Sure, but if you want to achieve something which isn't directly provided by an API you have to go out and look for a "workaround". Thats been done (especially in computer graphics) ever since computers are around ;-)