# Problems outputting gl_PrimitiveID to custom frame buffer object (FBO)

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpgpu, opengl-3

I have a very basic fragment shader which I want to output 'gl_PrimitiveID' to a fragment buffer object (FBO) which I have defined. Below is my fragment shader:

```
#version 150

uniform vec4 colorConst;

out vec4 fragColor;
out uvec4 triID;

void main(void)
{ 
   fragColor = colorConst;
   triID.r = uint(gl_PrimitiveID);
}
```

I setup my FBO like this:

```
  GLuint renderbufId0;
  GLuint renderbufId1;
  GLuint depthbufId;
  GLuint framebufId;


  // generate render and frame buffer objects
  glGenRenderbuffers( 1, &renderbufId0 );
  glGenRenderbuffers( 1, &renderbufId1 );
  glGenRenderbuffers( 1, &depthbufId   );
  glGenFramebuffers ( 1, &framebufId   );


  // setup first renderbuffer (fragColor)
  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbufId0);
  glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA,    gViewWidth, gViewHeight);


  // setup second renderbuffer (triID)
  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbufId1);
  glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGB32UI, gViewWidth, gViewHeight);


  // setup depth buffer
  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthbufId);
  glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, gViewWidth, gViewHeight);


  // setup framebuffer
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebufId);  
  glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbufId0);
  glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbufId1);
  glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,  GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthbufId  );


  // check if everything went well
  GLenum stat = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);  
  if(stat != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) { exit(0); }


  // setup color attachments
  const GLenum att[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
  glDrawBuffers(2, att);


  // render mesh
  RenderMyMesh()


  // copy second color attachment (triID) to local buffer
  glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
  glReadPixels(0, 0, gViewWidth, gViewHeight, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, data);
```

For some reason glReadPixels gives me a 'GL_INVALID_OPERATION' error? However if i change the internal format of renderbufId1 from 'GL_RGB32UI' to 'GL_RGB' and I use 'GL_FLOAT' in glReadPixels instead of 'GL_UNSIGNED_INT' then everything works fine. Does anyone know why I am getting the 'GL_INVALID_OPERATION' error and how I can solve it?

Is there an alternative way of outputting 'gl_PrimitiveID'?

PS: The reason I want to output 'gl_PrimitiveID' like this is explained here: [Picking triangles in OpenGL core profile when using glDrawElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079361/picking-triangles-in-opengl-core-profile-when-using-gldrawelements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> glReadPixels(0, 0, gViewWidth, gViewHeight, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, data);

As stated [on the OpenGL Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_format), you need to use `GL_RED_INTEGER` when transferring true integer data. Otherwise, OpenGL will try to use floating-point conversion on it.

BTW, make sure you're using [`glBindFragDataLocation`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBindFragDataLocation) to set up which buffers those fragment shader outputs go to. Alternatively, you can [set it up explicitly in the shader](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Type_Qualifiers#Fragment_shader_buffer_output) if you're using GLSL 3.30 or above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did the trick. Do you also happen to know how (if possible) to output 'gl_PrimitiveID' in a single 'uint' instead of a color component of a 'vec3'?

Comment: @WesDec: If you want to write to a `uint`, then just write to a `uint`. There's no rule that outputs (or inputs) have to be vector types. And there's no rule that output images need to have all four values; GL_RUI32 is a perfectly valid [image format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format). Also, there's no such thing as a "color component of a 'vec3'". ".r" means the same thing as ".x", which means the same thing as ".s". All of the swizzle masks mean the same thing.

Comment: Thanks I tried to use GL_R32UI instead of GL_RGB32UI in the second 'glRenderbufferStorage' call above, but I get an GL_INVALID_ENUM error? Could it be that its just not supported by my OpenGL drivers (Im on linux)? I know that the swizzle masks mean the same but the 'glReadPixels' parameters makes you to think of them as "color" "depth" or "stencil"  (GL_RED, GL_RGBA, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, etc.) which was why I was referring to them as "color component of a 'vec3'".

Comment: @WesDec: If your drivers can take `GL_RGB32UI`, then they should be able to take `GL_R32UI`. So it sounds like you need to update your drivers.

Comment: That's strange.. I'm on the newest ATI FGLRX drivers and I get the above error when I use GLR32UI.